# Parse array seems to store locally to my app session

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform

I have a weird bug in my app that I haven't seen before. Basically I have two views - User Profile and Edit Profile. In the User Profile view, I retrieve two things from Parse:

1. An array of strings telling the order of the user's profile photos (e.g. ["pic1", "pic3", "pic2"])
2. The photo files themselves (up to 6)

In the Edit Profile View, the user is able to upload new photos as well as rearrange the order array. The view also has a button to close the view and discard any changes as seen here:

```
@IBAction func cancelTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

The problem is that if I make any changes to photos order array such as rearranging it or appending to it, then hit the "Cancel" button, the view dismisses as it should. However, when I go back into the Edit Profile view or even if I close the User Profile then reopen that, both views show the new order array that wasn't supposed to be saved because I hit the "Cancel" button. The only way I can fix is by closing the app and reopening.

Is the array being saved locally to the iPhone? Please let me know if you need any more info or to see more code!

Edit: Forgot to mention, when I look in Parse the values aren't stored on there, but the Xcode logs say the array is changed when reloading the view.

Edit 2: Here is the instantiation of self.photoOrder:

```
var photoOrder:NSMutableArray = []
```

currentuser instantiation from Constants.swift

```
var currentuser = PFUser.currentUser()
```

Comment: How are you loading/saving the existing photo order array? Do you pass the values from the main view to the edit profile view or does the view load the values itself?

Comment: The Edit Profile view loads them itself as a part of viewDidLoad. Looks like this: self.photoOrder = currentuser.objectForKey("photoOrder") as! NSMutableArray

Comment: Could you add more code from the edit profile view controller? The declaration of `self.photoOrder` and instantiation of the `currentuser` object are interesting to solve your problem.

Comment: Ok great. I added it to the bottom of the post. However, the current user declaration occurs outside of the Edit Profile view and works fine in other parts of the app. Should I still include?

Comment: We could solve your problem when you include the code where you're accessing the `currentuser` object. That should solve my question, if you're passing the reference to a global `currentuser` object when you declare the edit profile view.

Comment: Cool just updated the edit again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how your reorder method looks like and if your calling the save method on the PFUser object when reording is done. It seems like you're overwritting the `photoOrder` attribute in your edit profile view somehow.

#### Solution 1

A simple solution would be to backup the current value when you load the view:

```
var photoOrderBackup:NSMutableArray = []

// viewDidLoad
self.photoOrder = currentuser.objectForKey("photoOrder") as! NSMutableArray
self.photoOrderBackup = currentuser.objectForKey("photoOrder") as! NSMutableArray
```

Then you got the chance to apply the backup values when the user cancels the operations.

```
@IBAction func cancelTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    currentUser.photoOrder = self.photoOrderBackup; // Apply backup value
    // Perhaps add the save method here after you've overwritten the photoOrder value
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

#### Solution 2

If the changes aren't saved to the currentuser object yet, refreshing the object could help to dismiss pending changes.

```
@IBAction func cancelTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    currentUser.refresh() // Refresh object with local data
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I also added currentuser.refresh() on the view. Somehow that snuck out of the code and I think was the culprit... using both solutions for now to be safe.